# Adding scrollview crashes app

Tags: android, xml

I am as an assignment creating an app for valentines day, I am making a love letter generator. I can only use one activity so I created a textview set visibility to gone. The love letter was a little long so i wanted a scroll view. Adding that crashed the app. please help

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/ename"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:hint="@string/name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/epname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ename"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:hint="@string/pname" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bnext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/nxt" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/Email"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/bnext"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/bnext"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/prmt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/epname"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="@string/Prompt"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/prmt"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:entries="@array/opts" />
```

This works fine
I added scroll view to text view1

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/bnext"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/bnext" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</ScrollView>
```

this crashes. 
LOGCAT

```
> 02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.assignment3/com.example.assignment3.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #63: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2253)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1290)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5109)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:991)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #63: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5665)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5786)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1776)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1700)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:56)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:741)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:276)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1897)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at com.example.assignment3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
02-03 12:14:05.191: E/AndroidRuntime(30264):    ... 11 more
```

TIA

Comment: Please post logcat with the error.

Comment: @Arjun Krishnan : try my answer

Comment: My case is different. I put it here for some one got the problem like me. The scrollview can contain only ONE child (TextView, LinearLayout...). So if you try to put many controls as level 1 childs of a ScrollView, that will cause an error. If you have many controls and want to put them inside a scrollview, you should wrap them in a container, like a LinearLayout. Then, put the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView, as the only one child.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting that error because you haven't supply any `width` and `height` for that `TextView`
in your layout. The layout should be something like this

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/bnext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/bnext" >
    <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

`android:visibility="gone"` set this attribute for `parent LinearLayout`

Comment: Thankyou so much!. had to edit it a little bit but works now!

Answer (score 2):

Scroll-view Must contain a parent View Group to all of it's child. Text view isn't a View Group. Add Linear Layout OR Relative Layout as a parent to your text view which is inside Scroll View. See this for further reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html. Use the below layout and your issue will be solved.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/bnext"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/bnext" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK You must need a view inside the `ScrollView` you can not directly add the views inside `ScrollView` you are suppose to add some layout i.e.`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`... in your `ScrollView` and inside that layout you can add your views.

Adding direct child or view in `ScrollView` will not be allowed.

Try as below:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/bnext"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/bnext" >
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
     >

 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the coding it will work

```
     <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/bnext"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/bnext" >
        <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: No it doesn't. I have a relative layout on top of the xml.

Comment: how much content your TextView has

Comment: Nothing until user makes a few selections

Comment: make the height of the scrollview check my edit answer

Comment: Nope. It isn't. THanks for trying.